# How does the ternary operator work in the wordpress loop post?

Tags: php, loop

Okay so I kind of understand that ternary operators work like

```
  condition ? TRUE : FALSE
```

However I'm looking a simple loop to get my posts that I have

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
while(have_posts()): the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
 ?>
```

The question I have is where is the ? in this syntax. Why is the `:` used when according to the

```
   condition ? TRUE : FALSE
```

Whatever comes after the semicolon is when that statement `(like have_posts())` is FALSE?

Answer (score 3):

The double colon in this case is part of the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).
That's **not** the ternary operator.

You could also write instead:

```
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();
        the_content();
    }
}
```

I prefer the second style, most code editors enable automatic folding with it, so I can close parts I don't need to see.